# How to make firebase image URL to be cached without having to put it in static folder?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I have the following logic in my react app where I use a firestore-storage imgae url, my image is on firestore-storage

```js
const imgLink = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/somepnglink

<img src={imgLink} />
```

my network tab image second loading ! first load gives 200 as it is the first time the image has load
[image: IMG network tab]

[image: Water fall]

previously, when I stored my images in react static folder, they got cached in browser memory, now I have to wait for the response to happen then that image loads!!
how to make the browser cache my images from firbase-stroage without having to to call and wait for the response each time since my images then don't load at time? I can tolerate the indicial loading...
not an issue.
but after that the images should be cached in browser so why not load them form there instantly without having to wait for the call to server ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have the `cache-control` header in your request? You can specify that using [`cacheControl`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/storage.settablemetadata.md#settablemetadatacachecontrol) in object metadata while uploading the file or using `updateMetadata()` function to add that for existing files.

**Without Cache-Control header:**

[image]

**With Cache-Control header:**

[image]

By default, the header will be set to `private, max-age=0`. You can use `updateMetadata()` as shown below:

```
await updateMetadata(storageRef, {
  cacheControl: 'public, max-age=300',
})
```

Alternatively, you can use the [Google Cloud Storage](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser) console to edit metadata manually.